# accidentally removed pip from RHEL 8.7, now system not working

Tags: rhel, python3

OS: `RHEL 8.7`
I had an issue with python. Was trying to resolve it and accidentally removed `pip` with the command `yum remove python3-pip`. Tried this method

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069

It gives the error

> "Cannot find rpm nevra "fish-3.5.1-1.1.x86_64"

Now system is starting with command line. Even though the default-target is graphical.

Comment: If you removed it with `yum remove python3-pip`, why did you not try to install it using `yum install python3-pip` again?

Comment: I guess more than just python3-pip was removed. Was it removed trying to run `yum undo ...` but with the wrong history value? Can you give details about what you ran when trying the linked method and about what it wrote it would be about to add or remove?

Comment: I did tried installing it using the command mentioned, but it installed only 2 dependencies and thats it.
When I removed it, there were almost 118 dependencies there were removed.
And no, `yum history undo` was used with correct ID value which was number `43`.
It gave the error I mentioned in my question. Please check the last two lines.